# First row of the cell as table header - Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I make the first row of the cell as the table header?

Code:

```
clc;
clear;
close all;

myCell = {'RowA', 'RowB', 'RowC'; 11, 22, 33;11, 22, 33}
myTable = cell2table(myCell);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>> myTable = cell2table(myCell(2:end,:),'VariableNames',myCell(1,:))

myTable =

  2×3 table

    RowA    RowB    RowC
    ____    ____    ____

     11      22      33 
     11      22      33
```